# How to get rid of library root mark in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, setuptools, pyramid

I've started working on a Pyramid application, which requires `setup.py` usage, but as soon as I built the app, my `app` folder was marked as *library root*.

It is not convenient, because when I open a file, it is also opened under *External Libraries* unfolding it. This can be "fixed" by removing check on *Always Select Opened File*, but I like this feature, so I don't want to disable it.

I've also tried to tweak *Project Structure* in settings, but it didn't help.

**How to get rid of this _library_root_ mark?**

[image: example]

UPD. Contents of `setup.py`:

```py
setup(
    name='app',
    version=0.1,
    description='Blog with CMS',
    classifiers=[
      "Programming Language :: Python",
      "Framework :: Pylons",
      "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP",
      "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: WSGI :: Application"
    ],
    keywords="web services",
    author='',
    author_email='',
    url='',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=['cornice', 'waitress'],
    entry_points="""\
    [paste.app_factory]
    main=app:main
    """,
    paster_plugins=['pyramid']
)
```

Comment: Have you try to right click the sd-blog folder and mark directory as "Source Root"? Also could we see your setup.py content?

Comment: @HansDaigle yes, I've tried marking both `sd-blog` and `app` folders as Source Root, but it didn't remove the _library root_ thing. Added setup.py to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why it happens is PyCharm adds `sd-blog/app` to the interpreter paths once you `pip install -e` in order to be able to provide completion for `app` objects. Possible workaround:

1. remove `app` from the interpreter paths

   [image]
2. mark `sd-blog/app` as a source root to restore the code insight broken in the step 1

Comment: For me, this worked, but I had to also mark the directory as a "Library Root".